# Why isn't the QuillJS setContent displaying anything when I set it to a JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, quill

I'm trying to create an array that displays the replies to a blog post in uneditable quill boxes. However, when I'm trying to grab the data from my html code, the setContent isn't working. I did some console logging, and found that the data is being retrieved correctly, a stringified JSON object. I also tried setting the content to other values, a raw JSON object, and that works perfectly. What's going wrong here?

````
var data = document.querySelectorAll(".answers .answer data");
var answerQuill;
for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    answerQuill = new Quill('#disp'+i.toString(), {
        modules: {toolbar: false},
        theme: 'snow'
    });
    answerQuill.setContents(JSON.parse(data[i].value), 'api');
    answerQuill.enable(false);
};```
````

Comment: Sorry but I think your question title is wrong. Did you mean Why isn't the QuillJS setContent displaying anything when I set it to a JSON Object? because the way I read it is that the setContent is displaying stuff when it shouldn't. I just want to make sure you get the correct answer.

Comment: Are you able to provide a minimal working example of this ?

Comment: Not too sure how to do that on this platform, but here is the one of the data[i].values I'm trying to parse: ```{"answer":"{\"ops\":[{\"insert\":\"No I disagree\\n\"}]}"}``` 

I have never seen the object name ("answer") before the "ops" in quill deltas, but then again, I am new to this.

Comment: So far, I've tried filtering out the "answer" part by doing 
```let parsed = JSON.parse(data[i].value); 
answerQuill.setContents(parsed.answer, 'api');``` but no luck still

Comment: Update: I tried doing ```anwerQuill.setContents({"ops":[{"insert":"No I disagree\n"}]}, 'api');``` and it worked perfectly. Strange because I copied the delta from console logging one of the data[i] values. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
I got it working, but I don't understand my solution lol.
Apparently I had to parse this twice?? Not sure why, but it works now. Huh.

```
let parsed = JSON.parse(data[i].value);
answerQuill.setContents(JSON.parse(parsed.answer), 'api');
answerQuill.enable(false);
```